# Apache Flink: Trigger not firing when using BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

When using a BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor, the trigger is not firing. However, the trigger fires when using custom timestamp extractor with similar watermark.

Sample code below:
1.Assigner as anonymous class which works fine

```
AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks<Tuple2<Rule, T>> assigner = new AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks<Tuple2<Rule, T>>() {
  @Override
  public long extractTimestamp(Tuple2<Rule, T> element, long previousElementTimestamp) {
    return System.currentTimeMillis();
  }

  @Override
  public final Watermark getCurrentWatermark() {
    return new Watermark(System.currentTimeMillis()-100);
  }
};
```

2.BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor assigner which doesn't work

```
AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks<Tuple2<Rule, T>> assigner = new BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor<Tuple2<Rule, T>>(Time.milliseconds(100)) {
  @Override
  public long extractTimestamp(Tuple2<Rule, T> element) {
    return System.currentTimeMillis();
  }
};
```

Do you see any difference in the approaches?

Answer (score 1):

Answer copied from flink mailing [list](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Trigger-not-firing-when-using-BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor-td17714.html):

> The difference is that the Watermarks from
>   BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor are based on the greatest timestamp of
>   all previous events. That is, if you do not receive new events, the Watermark
>   will not advance. In contrast, your custom implementation of
>   AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks always advances the Watermark based on the wall
>   clock.

Since I was using a small static set of events, the watermark was not advancing when using BOOTE.